# Can we develop a Python API which wraps R code

Tags: python, r

I have a working R script. Can this be wrapped in a Python code so it can be deployed as an API ?

Comment: Was posting this question there really faster than doing a Google search with the exact same title ?

Comment: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As mentioned in an earlier post, things that are not easy in R can be relatively simple in other languages. Another example would be connecting to Amazon Web Services. In relation to s3, although there are a number of existing packages, many of them seem to be deprecated, premature or platform-dependent. (I consider the cloudyr project looks promising though.)
>
> If there isn’t a comprehensive R-way of doing something yet, it may be necessary to create it from scratch. Actually there are some options to do so by using AWS Command Line Interface, AWS REST API or wrapping functionality of another language.

http://jaehyeon-kim.github.io/2015/11/Quick-Test-to-Wrap-Python-in-R.html